# How to convert datetime in seconds ANGULAR JS

Tags: angularjs, datetime

I am fetching data from JSON in my controller and need to convert it into seconds.

```
[
    {
        "Id": "0",
        "Name": "Subscriber",
        "ItemsCount": 5,
        "ItemsFailedCount": 6,
        "ExecutionStart": "2015-08-01T08:01:00.9748076+01:00",
        "ExecutionEnd": "2015-08-01T08:01:00.9748076+01:00"
    }
]
```

What I am trying to achieve is getting the difference between `"ExecutionStart" and "ExecutionEnd"` in seconds.

I have looked upon for the solution of this on internet and couldn't find any solution unfortunately. So I have nothing to show that I've tried.

Kindly help.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create Date objects from the date strings:

```
var executionStart = new Date(data[0].ExecutionStart);
var executionEnd = new Date(data[0].ExecutionEnd);
```

Then subtract the dates and divide by 1000 because difference will be in milliseconds and there are 1000 milliseconds in a second.

```
var diffSeconds = (executionEnd - executionStart) / 1000;
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o7eroydx/2/)

Answer (score 1):

solution using `date.parse();`

```
var data = [
    {
        "Id": "0",
        "Name": "Subscriber",
        "ItemsCount": 5,
        "ItemsFailedCount": 6,
        "ExecutionStart": "2015-08-01T08:01:00.9748076+01:00",
        "ExecutionEnd": "2015-08-01T08:01:10.9748076+01:00"
    }
];


var executionStarts = Date.parse(data[0].ExecutionStart);
var executionEnds =  Date.parse(data[0].ExecutionEnd);

var diffSeconds = (executionEnds - executionStarts)/1000;

alert(diffSeconds);
```